# Does renaming of COM Class property breaks backward compatibility?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have COM dll that is used as an API for application. I have old property `SomeProperty` which is not used for years and just returns `E_NOTIMPL` code.

Will it break backward compatibility for dll clients if I rename property to `Reserved`? In other words, are clients required to rebuild their applications to continue to work with my dll?

Comment: Is it an IDispatch interface ("lazy loading" or an IUnknown interface ("early loading"), eg: show us some code.

Comment: Have a read of [Changing Interfaces in a Backward Compatible Manner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/changing-interfaces-in-a-backward-compatible-manner)

Comment: if this is not IDispatch(Ex) - name of the method not play any role and you can rename it if want. in case IDispatchEx - you need also adjust `GetIDsOfNames` ( and more if rare case Ex )